# Get single value from repeatable fields

Tags: php

I have created a wordpress custom meta field that is a repeatable field, meaning that in the admin section I can add/delete entries to a single field using jquery.  The output is an array and I am able to make that work.

I want to be able to set each returned value as a variable to do other php stuff with.  Here is my current code to access the field:

```
<?php
$repeatable_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);
if ( $repeatable_fields ) :
foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) :
$staff = $field['team_staff'];
echo $staff.'<br>';
endforeach;
endif; 
?>
```

This creates a list of staff.  Now I need to make each staff member into a variable so I can get more info on that staff member.  How can I separate them out like that and keep track of the variables because there will be different numbers of staff returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change $staff to array :

```
<?php
$staff = array();
$repeatable_fields = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);
if ( $repeatable_fields ) :
foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) :
$staff[] = $field['team_staff'];
endforeach;
endif; 
?>
```

and where you want use :

```
foreach ($staff as $smth){
echo $smth;
}
```